# Tone output with AVR

Tags: avr, sound

I've got a keypad hooked up to an ATMega168 and its supposed to play various tones depending on the button pressed while the respective key is held down. I'm generating these tones by alternating the state of the port the speaker is attached too at 2* the rate of its frequency (or close enough to it)

It works as intended save for the fact that every tone is the same. Is there a limitation to the frequency it can output this way? If so is there a better way of doing it?

I've tried it with an LED at a far lower frequencies so I know the keypad subroutine is working as intended.

```
if (keychar == '1'){
                    while (keypressed()){
                        PORTB |=(1<<PB1); //Set Port B to high
                        delay_ms(1000/524); //for note fequ *2 (50% duty cycle)
                        PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1); //Set Port B to low
                        delay_ms(1000/524); //for note fequ *2 (50% duty cycle)
                    }
                }
                if (keychar == '2'){
                    while (keypressed()){
                        PORTB |=(1<<PB1); //Set Port B to high
                        delay_ms(1000/588); //for note fequ *2 (50% duty cycle)
                        PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1); //Set Port B to low
                        delay_ms(1000/588); //for note fequ *2 (50% duty cycle)
                    }
                }
.....
                if (keychar == '7'){
                    while (keypressed()){
                        PORTB |=(1<<PB1); //Set Port B to high
                        delay_ms(1000/988); //for note fequ *2 (50% duty cycle)
                        PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1); //Set Port B to low
                        delay_ms(1000/988); //for note fequ *2 (50% duty cycle)
                    }
                }
.....
```

Comment: delay_ms() only takes integers, which in addition to the fact that you are doing integer division explains why you keep getting the same value.  You almost certainly want to use a hardware timer for this, dividing the clock down to produce an output frequency.

Comment: Well, that was my fallback plan. There a particular page in the documentation I should start with? 143 gonna do the job?

Comment: 143 whats?  You can presumably find some example for tone generation with the hardware timer via a web search.  If you get desperate for a near term demo, there's always the Arduino ecosystem...

Comment: Page 143 in the ATMega documentation.

Comment: @Redacted Just sit down with a piece of paper and work things out. You know you have different frequencies to create. Have you ever heard of something called the "greatest common divisor," or GCD, for example? For example, the GCD(524 588 988)=4. Perhaps you could use that concept to reduce the values to 131, 147, and 247? And this may provide some clues about how to set up the timer. The point here is that you sit down with paper and pencil and work out a method to get from A to B. Then you figure out how to implement it. It's just brain-work, so to speak.

Comment: I'm going to use the NOP assembly function. It takes about 113 microseconds to execute with the 14.something or other MHz clock I'm using. for(time=0;time<=8959;time++){NOP;} should give C4

Answer (score 1):

they're all the same because you use the same number.

1000/524 == 1

1000/588 == 1

1000/988 == 1

That's just the way integer division works in C

You'll get better results if you use one of the hardware timers directly.

Answer (score 0):

Justme's comments got me to look into this a little deeper.

delay_ms() passes a value to another function called delay_us().

```
inline void delay_us(uint16_t us) {
  //_delay_us(us);
  uint16_t i;
  for(i=0; i<us; i++) {
    NOP;    // two is right for 8MHz, tested by mikey and robtruax
    NOP;

    NOP;    // so adding 7 more will yield a slightly slow clock (1.017us)
    NOP;
    NOP;
    NOP;
    NOP;
    NOP;
    NOP;
  }
}
```

So assuming the guys who originally wrote that are correct, a for loop along with 9 NOPs take around 1us. With that assumption I wrote another function to exploit this.

```
void tone(uint16_t freq){

    PORTB |=(1<<PB1); //Set Port B to high
    delay_us(freq);
    PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1); //Set Port B to low
    delay_us(freq);
}
```

where freq is 1000/(f*2000*1.017). The tone is far nicer and so I assume closer to the desired frequency. I don't have an oscilloscope to confirm this, I'm going by ear and its kind of hard to compare sine wave audio to square wave audio. Close enough for my purposes.

Comment: Have you actually tried what you suggest? The for loop jumping and variable comparing takes many times more cycles than a NOP, so you get many times slower delay. Wouldn't it just be better to use the microsecond delays or cycle based delay loops provided by avr-libc directly?

Comment: It produces a tone, as to whether its the correct tone I don't know. Close enough to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is to use timer hardware for tone generation, but for simple test purposes of waiting in loops, the avr-libc provides microsecond delays and cycle based delay loops that can also be used.